# How to split a comma and colon separated column into respective columns in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, strsplit

Say for example I have a column that looks something like:

```
name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC
```

How could I split this column into separate columns such that it would yield a result similar as a data frame to:

```
   name   | Age | City
1 Michael | 31  | NYC
```

I've attempted to use mtabulate from the qdapTools package but it only resulted with boolean value columns.

Comment: `library(tidyverse);

tibble(Text="name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC") %>% 
  extract(Text, c("name", "Age", "City"), "name:(.+),Age:(.*),City:(.*)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, it can be done with `read.dcf`

```
out <- type.convert(as.data.frame( 
         read.dcf(textConnection(paste(gsub(",", "\n", df1$col1),
        collapse = "\n\n")))
), as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> out
     name Age City
1 Michael  31  NYC
2 Michael  31  NYC
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   separate_rows(col1, sep = ",\\s*") %>% 
   separate(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep = ":") %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2) %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  name    Age   City 
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 Michael 31    NYC  
2 Michael 31    NYC
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC",
 "name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution because in connection to my work it's best I use base R as much as possible. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_split_fixed` from the `stringr` package:

```r
library(stringr)

df[c("name", "Age", "City")] <- str_split_fixed(
    gsub("\\w+:", "", df$col), ",", 3
)
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(col=c("name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `separate` your single column dataframe into three columns, then remove the texts before colon `:`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(col, into = c("name", "Age", "city"), sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("^.+?:", "", .x)))

     name Age city
1 Michael  31  NYC
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(col = "name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- "name:Michael,Age:31,City:NYC"

data |>
  tibble() |>
  separate_rows(data, sep = ",") |>
  separate(data, into = c("name", "value")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   name    Age   City 
#>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Michael 31    NYC
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>